# How to use input/textarea focus as a condition for hotkeys

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I have AutoHotkey set up in a way that is recognises <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> keystrokes as <kbd>Back</kbd>/<kbd>Forward</kbd> navigation in Chrome.

Problem is that it also recognises those keys being pressed while I am entering text in text boxes. However when entering text, I'd would like those key combinations to carry out different function - jump to beginning/end of the line, similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Is there a way to have one mapping working for text boxes and another mapping for everything else in AutoHotkey?

Comment: This is going to be tricky because AHK can't detect individual elements within the web content, but I have some tricks up my sleeve for making this work without much work. ;)

Comment: What are your tricks, @iglvzx?

Answer (score 8):

The deepest AutoHotkey (AHK) can detect within Google Chrome, related to web content, is the `Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1` control. This control is the **viewport** for web content. Our `input` and `textarea` HTML elements are a little deeper, inside the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) of the rendered content.

So, we need to find a way to communicate through this wall between the HTML elements and AutoHotkey. Luckily, there is a player on the same side as the HTML who can speak AHK's lingo: **JavaScript**!

How so? To put it simply, JavaScript can perform an action when an element gains or loses focus. One of these actions can be changing the page title. This in turn changes Google Chrome's window title, and AHK can read window titles!

---

### Setup:

1. Install my [**InputFocusTitleChange.user.js**](https://raw.github.com/gist/3006931/InputFocusTitleChange.user.js) userscript. ([Source](https://gist.github.com/3006931))
2. Now you can use following syntax in AutoHotkey:

   ```
   SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

   #x:: ; normal hotkey
        ; do something
       return

   #IfWinActive, \[AHK\] - Google Chrome$
       #x:: ; input/textarea focus hotkey
            ; do something
           return

   #IfWinActive
   ```

---

### Demonstration:

When an HTML `input` or `textarea` element has focus, the userscript appends  `[AHK]` to the page title, changing Google Chrome's window title.

[image: window title] [image: google chrome]

AHK can use this characteristic, if the window's title ends in `"[AHK] - Google Chrome"` or not, to indirectly connect HTML `input`/`textarea` focus with a set of commands.

---

### Notes:

From my testing, there are two issues:

1. If the `input`/`textarea` is already focused when the page loads, `[AHK]` may not be added to the page title. You have to move focus away from the element and then back to get the title to change.
2. If the `input`/`textarea` element is dynamically generated after the page loads (this is also when the script loads), then those elements will not have any effect.

> *I will continue to work on this solution. If you have any suggestions or know of a way to counter these JavaScript issues, please feel free to let me know and/or contribute. The source is posted above and hosted on Github.*

Comment: Wow this is very detailed! I'll give it a shot soon! Thanks!

Comment: So how would I go about using this to insert the following:

`    #IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    BackSpace::Send, {Left}{Delete}`

...when in Chrome but not in a `textarea`/`input`?